# Search,replace text and save as based on text in document in Python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, operating-system, rename

All, I am just getting started with python and I thought this may be a good time to see if it can help me automate a lot of repeative tasks I have to complete.

I am using a script I found on Gethub that will search and replace and then write a new file with the name output.txt. It works fine, but Since I have lots of these files I need to be able to name them different names based on the Text in the final modified document.

To make this a little more difficult the name of the file is based on the text I will be modifing the document with.

So, basically  after I run this script, I have a file that sits at C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Scripts\Text_Find_and_Replace\Result with the name of output.txt in this Modified new file I would like to name it based on what text is in a particular line of the file. So in the modified file of output.txt I would like to have it rename the file to the plain text in line 35.

I have figured out how to read the line within the file using

```
import linecache
line = linecache.getline("readme.txt", 1)
line
>>> line
'This is Python version 3.5.1\n'
```

I just need to figure out how to rename the file based on the variable "line"
Any Ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import string
import re
## information/replacingvalues.txt this is the text of the values you want        in your final document
information = open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-        32\Scripts\Text_Find_and_Replace\information/replacingvalues.txt", 'r')
 #Text_Find_and_Replace\Result\output.txt This is the dir and the sum or    final document
output = open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Scripts\Text_Find_and_Replace\Result\output.txt", 'w')
#field = open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-    32\Scripts\Text_Find_and_Replace\Field/values.txt"
# Field is the file or words you will be replacing
field = open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-   32\Scripts\Text_Find_and_Replace\Field/values.txt", 'r')
##
##
# modified code for autohot key
# Text_Find_and_Replace\Test/remedy line 1.ahk is the original doc you want    modified
with open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-  32\Scripts\Text_Find_and_Replace\Test/remedy line 1.ahk", 'r') as myfile:
    inline = myfile.read()

#orig code
##with open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-    32\Scripts\Text_Find_and_Replace\Test/input.txt", 'r') as myfile:
##    inline = myfile.read()

informations  = []
fields = []
dictionary = {}
i = 0

for line in information:
    informations.append(line.splitlines())

for lines in field:
    fields.append(lines.split())
    i = i+1;

if (len(fields) != len(informations) ):
    print ("replacing values and values have different numbers")
    exit();
else:
    for i in range(0, i):
        rightvalue = str(informations[i])
        rightvalue = rightvalue.strip('[]')
        rightvalue = rightvalue[1:-1]

        leftvalue = str(fields[i])
        leftvalue = leftvalue.strip('[]')
        leftvalue = leftvalue.strip("'")

        dictionary[leftvalue] = rightvalue

robj = re.compile('|'.join(dictionary.keys()))
result = robj.sub(lambda m: dictionary[m.group(0)], inline)


output.write(result)
information.close;
output.close;
field.close;
```

I figured out how...

```
import os
import linecache
linecache.clearcache()
newfilename= linecache.getline("C:\python 3.5/remedy line 1.txt",37)
filename = ("C:\python 3.5/output.ahk")
os.rename(filename, newfilename.strip())

linecache.clearcache()
```

Comment: [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename), [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

Comment: your indentation is broken in the code.

Comment: @th2112: Tried fixing the indentation. Please take a look at the logic and fix it in case I broke it anywhere